# React-PDF/Rendered doesn't render image URL

Tags: reactjs, image, base64, preview, react-pdf

I use `react-pdf/renderer` in my app and managed to create PDF file with some images included. Images located locally (`the ones imported via import from 'imagePath'`) are loaded normally, but when I pass base64 encoded string, image is missing in PDF preview. As per doc, built in `<Image />` component can receive url but in my case it doesn't work. Anyone faced similar issues?